# Java EE project with Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, jakarta-ee

I have been using this kind of maven based project structure:

```
parent pom
    |
    |-------- WebTier (war module) JSF2+Richfaces/Primefaces+facelets
    |
    |-------- BusinessTier (ejb module) EJB 3.*+ timers
    |
    |-------- PersistenceTier (JPA2)
    |
    |-------- Utilities (jar)
    |
    |-------- IntegrationTier (ejb module) (RESTful webservices, 
              for example Email/Sms handling)
```

I am very comfortable with this kind of setup. Now I want to learn Spring as it is widely used and because I'll need it. As I have understood, I can get parts of the Spring framework and use them as part of the Java EE application. For example Spring mvc with some component based framework at my webtier for rich Uis. Replace EJB with Spring etc. How this project setup will differ when Spring is in use??

Comment: Spring doesn't enforce you to change your structure of your project. You can absolutely configure it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You want to learn spring that is a very good thing, because learning is always good thing. But here thing is that, you want to use spring in your project because you want to learning spring. **But you should think first that will spring required for your project at all or not?**

As per your project structure, it seems it will be working fine even if you don’t use spring in your project. Yes, few features of spring you can still add into your project. I will suggest, you should start learning, what spring is, it’s powers and try to figure it out, ***how and where it can be fit into your project***. I found **Spring by Example** by David Winterfeldt & **Spring Framework 3.1 Tutorial** by tutorialspoint.com, both books are quite good for beginners.

Comment: The book Pro Spring MVC with Web Flow from Adlibris.com seems to be very nice introduction to Spring. It has over 300 pages, so Spring is very comprehensive framework. It has a chapter also about organizing web projects and which tiers/layers there can be found.My goal is now to implement the Bookstore app with spring and some component based framework.